# UNIQUE constraint but only when column = something

Tags: sql, sqlite, pdo, constraints, unique

Is this possible in SQLite?

Like:

```
UNIQUE(col1, col2 = "something", col3),
```

What I mean by unique:

```
#1  col1=Foo | col2=Foo       | col3=Foo   > OK
#2  col1=Foo | col2=Foo       | col3=Foo   > OK
#3  col1=Foo | col2=something | col3=Foo   > OK
#4  col1=Foo | col2=something | col3=Foo   > Should fail because of #3
#5  col1=Foo | col2=something | col3=Bar   > OK
#6  col1=Foo | col2=something | col3=Bar   > Should fail because of #5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported directly; you have to implement it with a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER something_unique_check
BEFORE INSERT ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.col2 = 'something'
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(FAIL, '"something" record is not unique')
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE col1 = NEW.col1
      AND col2 = NEW.col2
      AND col3 = NEW.col3;
END;
```

Comment: Depends on whether you have an index on (col1,col2,col3) …

Comment: @CL.: You answered just a day after SQLite added support for partial indexes, could you kindly look into my answer and tell me if that works? I'm still running an old version of SQLite here.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested it but I think you can do that with [partial indexes in SQLite 3.8.0](http://www.sqlite.org/partialindex.html) (released 2013-08-26):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX
    "partial_index" ON "table" ("col1", "col2", "col3")
WHERE ("col2" = 'something');
```

I might be wrong though.

Comment: [Download](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) the command-line shell and try it out. (The documentation would already have told you what you did wrong.)

Comment: @CL.: Indeed, I overlooked the `LIKE` function.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using table-level `cheque` constraint

```
ALTER TABLE T
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_something CHECK (col2 != "something" OR (col1<>col2 AND col1<>col3 AND col2<>col3))
```

other option is to use trigger, but that's a more sophisticated approach.

Comment: This checks only a single record. This is not what `UNIQUE` is for.